# How to build a hexagon according to Poincaré model?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, geometric-construction

Given a side, I know how to build a hexagon in the euclidean geometry. How can i build it in the hyperbolic geometry according to the Poincaré model? By translating every step using hyperbolic circle it doesn't work. I use geogebra or cabrì.

Sorry for my English.
Thanks for help.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by "translating every step using hyperbolic circle", but since you are using the Poincaré model you only need to rotate successively a hyperbolic circle by an angle of $\pi/3$ around the origin.

Comment: How i can build it?

Comment: As I said: "rotate successively a hyperbolic circle by an angle of $\pi/3$ around the origin".

Answer (score 0):

Just the construction:

let r be the euclidean radius of the Poincare disk
Let C be the centre of the Poincare disk

let P be one of the vertices of the hexagon

- draw circle p  around C going through  P
- calculate $o = \frac{2 r^2}{\sqrt{3} |PC|} $
- draw a circle q around C with distance o
- rotate the ray CP $30^{\circ} $ giving ray $q_1$
- let $Q_1$ be the intersection of $q_1$ and circle q
- draw the circle $s_1$ with centre $Q_1$  going trough $P$

Then 5 times:

- Let $P_n$ be the intersection of $s_{n-1} $ and $p$
- rotate the ray $CQ_{n-1} 60^{\circ} $ giving ray $q_n$
- let $Q_n$ be the intersection of $q_n$ and circle $q$
- draw the circle $s_n$ with centre $Q_n$ going trough $P_{n-1}$

now you have the 6 vertices of your hexagon, and the sides are those parts of circles $s_n$ between them

Good luck